# Find the solution of the differential equation that satisfies ${{dP} \over {dt}} = 8\sqrt {Pt} ,\,P(1) = 5$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Please help. My homework is grading my answer as incorrect, but I can't tell what I did wrong. The second photo is the work of the problem done correctly but with dp/dt=2sqrt(Pt). I based my work off of this, but my answer is incorrect. Thank you!

The link to the question is:
[Q3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2gd0.png)

and here is my answer:
[C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GhNg.png)

Comment: Welcome MSE, please write what ever confuses you directly in your question! :)

Comment: I added the work from a similar question that I based my answer off of, if that helps you! I don't know what I did wrong, so I can't say specifically which step I am confused about.

Comment: Edit your question. Your title and Q3 say 8sqrt while the text and C say 2sqrt. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=8\sqrt{Pt}$$
$$\frac{dP}{\sqrt{P}}=8\sqrt{t}dt$$
$$\int \frac{dP}{\sqrt{P}}=\int 8\sqrt{t}dt$$
$$2\sqrt{P}=8\cdot \frac{t^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{3}{2}}+c=\frac{16}{3}t^{\frac{3}{2}}+c$$
By initial conditions, $P(1)=5$
$$2\sqrt{5}=\frac{16}{3}+c$$
$$c=2\sqrt{5}-\frac{16}{3}$$

The answer should be $$2\sqrt{P}=\frac{16}{3}t^{\frac{3}{2}}+2\sqrt{5}-\frac{16}{3}$$
$$\sqrt{P}=\frac{8}{3}t^{\frac{3}{2}}+\sqrt{5}-\frac{8}{3}$$
$$P=\left(\frac{8}{3}t^{\frac{3}{2}}+\sqrt{5}-\frac{8}{3}\right)^2$$

Comment: Wow very nice answer.......

Answer (score 0):

I think, I got your mistake. In fact, you have not done anything wrong! you just started by

$${{dP} \over {dt}} = 2\sqrt {Pt} ,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,P(1) = 5$$

while the main question was

$${{dP} \over {dt}} = 8\sqrt {Pt} ,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,P(1) = 5$$

That's all! :)